# Toshiba Laptop : Chicony Webcam locked by another application

Tags: laptop, windows-vista, webcam

When I try to connect my built-in webcam in Vista Home Premium it says "The cam was locked by another application."Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should install this [driver](http://go.notebookreview.com/?id=525X832&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdrivers.softpedia.com%2Fget%2FSCANNER-Digital-CAMERA-WEBCAM%2FOTHER-SCANNERS%2FAcer-Extensa-5210-Chicony-Webcam-Driver-57.shtml), follow [those](http://forum.notebookreview.com/showthread.php?t=149463) steps.